# Contract creating another contract using Web3 getting out of gas error despite gas value being large (e.g. 50,000,000)

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, testrpc, out-of-gas

I wrote a contract A that creates a new contract B and returns the address of the new contract B that's been created.  When I tested this on solidity browser it seems to work well, but when I tried to run the create method using web3, I keep getting this error:

```
        throw errors.InvalidResponse(result);
    ^
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
```

Here's my contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2; 
contract B { 
   int public id;
   function B(int _id) { 
     id = _id;
   }
} 

contract A { 
   address Baddress;
   function createB(int _id) returns (address) { 
     Baddress = new B(_id); 
     return Baddress;
   } 
}
```

Here's my Javascript code that attempts to run A's createB method:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.coinbase;
var Acontract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getdum","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"num","type":"int256"}],"name":"create","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]);

var A = Acontract.new({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
data: '{{compiled byte code}}', 
gas: '47000000'}, function (e, contract){
   console.log(e, contract);
   if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
     console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address);
     contract.createB(5000).then(console.log); // This line throws the error
   }
})
```

I've read many other related posts and could only find answers that suggest to use more gas, but no matter how much gas I sent with the transaction, it would throw the same error.  You can see I'm using a really large value for gas in the code. Can anyone help me identify what I'm doing wrong? I'm using solc Version: 0.4.9+commit.364da425.Darwin.appleclang, EthereumJS TestRPC v3.0.3, and node v6.4.0.

Comment: Are you using truffle? Also, I think you may have a typo in your code `.create(5000)` vs. `.createB(5000)`

Comment: Thank you for noticing the typo. I accidentally deleted the B there... I did try to use truffle, but when I used this command: `A.deployed().then(function(instance){return instance.createB(50)}).then(console.log)`, it returned a null contract address.  How do I get newly created B's contract address..?

Comment: I actually don't use truffle, but the promisified methods aren't native to web3 (yet!). `.createB().then()` won't work. That said, you can use a library like bluebird to promisify web3 anyway.

Comment: Oh I see. Although, do you think I can use `createB()` without a promise?

Comment: You can, it'll just return a transaction hash rather than a thenable. The standard way is to do that, then filter for an event the transaction creates.

Comment: Right, although in my case, it only returns error no matter how much gas I use. It's weird because there are so many tutorials on contracts creating other contracts, and none of them seemed to have problems with out of gas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After replicating this, I discovered the issue.

You'll need to specify the gas *again* when you send the `.createB()` transaction. That is, if you use `.createB(5000)`, it only uses the default gas limit of 90000 and fails. Setting the gas limit to higher, with `.createB(5000, {gas: 200000})` was successful for me. browser-solidity gives a more accurate value of `113598` for the transaction's cost.

Comment: Thank you! This indeed was the gas supply I missed. However, I'm still unable to get correct ID value of B due to an error of "invalid address" after calling B from its contract address returned in A. I've followed the example on Web3's documentation page using ```web3.eth.contract(abi).at(baddress).getB()``` where it threw that error. Although the previous error was resolved, this is where I had problems before on truffle and now web3.

Comment: Nvm! I fixed it after looking up eth.filter in your last comment. Thank you again for your help!!

Comment: cheers for this! spend ours debugging.